# Navigating records in a databound WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I'm fairly new to WPF and I've been reading many tutorials and yet while I could find many guides that showed how to bind data to textboxes and such, I couldn't find anything about navigating such data through back/forward/etc. buttons.

This is my current situation: I have a **Customer** class containing data on a single customer and a **Customers** class which is an ObservableCollection of customer.
Then data is loaded from an sqlite database (and this opens another can of worms because I don't know the exact approach for working this out but it doesn't really pertain to the current issue since I more or less got it to work) and every customer is added to the collection.

Then in the ViewModel for the main form I have the following stuff:

```
private Customer _objCustomer;
private Customers _customers;
private Customer _selectedCustomer;

public Customer Selection { get { return _selectedCustomer; }
        set
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(value, _selectedPartecipante)) { return; }
            _selectedCustomer = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged("Selection");
        }
    }

public Customers customers { get { return _partecipanti; }
    set { _customers = value; base.OnPropertyChanged("customers"); } }

    public Customer customer { get { return _objCustomer; } 
        set { _objCustomer = value; base.OnPropertyChanged("customer"); } }

    public string Name { get { return _objCustomer.Name; } set { _objCustomer.Name = value; base.OnPropertyChanged("Name"); } }

    public int Id { get { return _objCustomer.Id; } }

    public SubscriptionsViewModel()
    {
        _customers = Customers.LoadCustomers(); //This one loads the items from the database
        _objCustomers = _customers.First();
        _selectedCustomer = _objCustomer;
    }
```

This is probably wrong but I still can't find a way to fix it, what am I supposed to work to get navigation working?
And how do I get the data in the current record to be saved when pressing a certain button on the form?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the exact property in OnPropertyChanged("Customers");
In your case, the property is lower case.

Comment: And how would I bind the buttons to move to the next record?